# omp global memory fence / barrier

Tags: c++, gpu, openmp

Does OpenMP with target offloading on the GPU include a global memory fence / global barrier, similar to OpenCL?

```
barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

I've tried using inside a teams construct

```
#pragma omp target teams
{
    // Some initialization...

    #pragma omp distribute parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        // Some work...
    }

    #pragma omp barrier

    #pragma omp distribute parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        // Some other work depending on pervious loop
    }
}
```

However it seams that the barrier only works within a team, equivalent to:

```
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

I would like to avoid splitting the kernel into two, to avoid sending team local data to global memory just to load it again.

**Edit:** I've been able enforce the desired behavior using a global atomic counter and busy waiting of the teams. However this doesn't seem like a good solution, and I'm still wondering if there is a better way to do this using proper OpenMP

Answer (score 0):

A `barrier` construct only synchronizes threads in the current team. Synchronization between threads from different thread teams launched by a `teams` construct is not available. OpenMP's execution model doesn't guarantee that such threads will even execute concurrently, so using `atomic` constructs to synchronize between the threads will not work in general:

> Whether the initial threads concurrently execute the **teams** region is
> unspecified, and a program that relies on their concurrent execution for the
> purposes of synchronization may deadlock.

Note that the OpenCL `barrier` call only provides synchronization within a workgroup, even with the `CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE` argument. See [Barriers in OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890302/barriers-in-opencl) for more information on semantics of `CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE` versus `CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE`.

Comment: This is really interesting, I've seen multiple implementations using barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE) as a global barrier, but it looks like you're right. Do you know of any way to ensure the behavior of a global barrier in OpenMP? besides splitting the code into multiple kernels.